# Handling default value for int64_t representing an edge in an adjacency matrix

Tags: c++

I'm writing an adjacency matrix, in this moment I'm trying to figure out how to indicate a default numeric value for an unassigned edge. There is the macro `_I64_MAX` but it is said that it's a bad practice to use macros. I wish to know if there's other way to assign such value (as a keyword as in the case of `nullptr` instead of `NULL`) or if what I'm doing is OK.

Why don't I use `0`? Because the distance for an edge which start and end vertex is the same is:
$$e=(v_i,v_i);~~~||e||=0$$

```cpp
AdjacencyMatrix::AdjacencyMatrix(const SinglyLinkedList &vertices) : vertices_(vertices)
{
    this->edge_matrix_ = new int64_t *[this->vertices_.Size()];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->vertices_.Size(); i++)
    {
        this->edge_matrix_[i] = new int64_t[this->vertices_.Size()];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < this->vertices_.Size(); j++)
        {
            this->edge_matrix_[i][j] = _I64_MAX;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question. Maybe a mod will move it to stack-overflow or something like that.

Comment: You may find this page interesting: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Comment: No because it is related to best practices, at first I doubted but I read the faq

Comment: It's OK to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not **"What is the best practice regarding X?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use of macros**

In this case, the macro you using is from a library header that was included with your compiler. This header (ultimately `limits.h`, although `<climits>` is usually used with C++ code) is also used by C code, so C++ specific language features cannot be used. These are OK to use.

The C++ way of referencing a minimum value for a type is to make use of [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) (in the `<limits>`) header. In your case, you can replace `_I64_MAX` with `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()`.

**Other notes**

All of the references to `this->` are unnecessary and can be removed from your code. You rarely need to specify this in C++ code (there a few specific cases where it is needed, like for variable name disambiguation or calling a function thru a member function pointer).

The `for` loop might be able to be rewritten using iterators or the [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) style if this is supported by the `SinglyLinkedList` type.